# Writing a SQL Statement to group data

Tags: sql

I need help writing a SQL statement (I'm having a senior moment here):
Equipment Table contains all items in inventory:

```
 Tables -
 Equip: EquipID, Barcode, ModelRefId.
 Model: ModelID, AcceptsCards, MakeRefId.
 Make:  MakeId.
```

I have another table, "Contents" that contains the Equip of the item that "Accepts cards", then a list of each EquipId that is inside that item:

```
 Contents:  EquipRefId, EquipCardRefId.
example:  100  1000
          100  1001
          101  1002
          101  1003
          ...
```

I want to create a statement to return ALL the items (equipment) that accepts cards (WHERE Model.AcceptsCards = true), AND any cards (also equipment) that are in the item (basically, a list of empty PC chassis, a list of all PC Cards, and then the Contents is the PC id and cards in that PC.

```
 PC1 Make Model Barcode
      Card1 Make Model Barcode
      Card2 Make Model Barcode  ....etc...
 PC2 Make Model Barcode
      Card1 Make Model Barcode
      Card2 Make Model Barcode  ....etc...
  ...etc...
```

To return all the equipment that accepts cards (e.g. All the PC chassis):

```
SELECT Make.sMakeName, Model.sModelName, Make.iMakeID, Model.iModelID, Equip.iEquipID, Equip.sBarcode, Equip.sSerialNo
FROM Equip RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
Make LEFT OUTER JOIN 
Model ON Make.iMakeID = Model.iMakeRef ON Equip.iModelRef = Model.iModelID
WHERE     (Model.iAcceptsCards = 1)
ORDER BY Make.sMakeName, Model.sModelName
```

..but I am not sure how to include/merge/join the Contents table.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you have the first query (all the equipment that accepts cards), and want to add to its result results of the second query, based on the first one (contents of each item in the first query).

There is basically two different ways.
In your case Query_A is like

```
select Id_A, Make_A, Model_A, Barcode_A
  from [some joining of tables Equip, Model, Make] ...
  where ...
```

And Query_B is like

```
select Id_B, Make_B, Model_B, Barcode_B
  from Query_A
  join Contents on ...
  join [some joining of tables Equip, Model, Make] ...
  where ...
```

First of all if you need the results to be ordered like in your question, you will have to make sure that the Query_B has Id column of the Query_A that you can use for grouping each parent item and its contents together.

The **first way** is to just union results of both queries:

```
select *
from (
  select Id_A, Id_A as Id, Make_A, Model_A, Barcode_A
    from [some joining of tables Equip, Model, Make] ...
    where ...
  union all
  select Id_A, Id_B, Make_B, Model_B, Barcode_B
    from (
      select Id_A
        from [some joining of tables Equip, Model, Make] ...
        where ...
    ) as Query_A
    join Contents on ...
    join [some joining of tables Equip, Model, Make] ...
    where ...
) x
order by Id_A, Id
```

If your server supports `CTE` then statement can be simplified:

```
with Query_A as (
  select Id_A, Make_A, Model_A, Barcode_A
    from [some joining of tables Equip, Model, Make] ...
    where ...
)
select Id_A, Id_A, Make_A, Model_A, Barcode_A
  from Query_A
union all
select Id_A, Id_B, Make_B, Model_B, Barcode_B
  from Query_A
  join Contents on ...
  join [some joining of tables Equip, Model, Make] ...
  where ...
```

The **second way** is to duplicate results of the first query and then to turn each double into its contents:

```
select
  case x.x when 0 then Query_A.Id_A else Id_B end as Id,
  case x.x when 0 then Query_A.Make_A else Make_B end as Make,
  case x.x when 0 then Query_A.Model_A else Model_B end as Model,
  case x.x when 0 then Query_A.Barcode_A else Barcode_B end as Barcode
  from (
    select Id_A, Make_A, Model_A, Barcode_A
      from [some joining of tables Equip, Model, Make] ...
      where ...
  ) as Query_A
  cross join (select 0 as x union all select 1) as x
  left join Contents on (x.x = 1 and ...)
  left join [some joining of tables Equip, Model, Make] ...
  where (x.x = 0 or Id_B is not null) and ...
  order by Id_A, Id
```

Comment: In MS-SQL the 'from equip. make, model. creates a CROSS JOIN by default which returns an incredible number of records. I don't think this will work!

Comment: Sorry, I was inaccurated in explaining. When I wrote `from equip. make, model` I did not mean literally CROSS JOIN of the tables but just wanted to generally refer to some joining of the tables which you will wrote as you need. SQL statements in my answer are not a neat solution, but give an idea in general.